# Coding of next and back button

Tags: android, sqlite

In this code i am displaying questions by matching the tablename one by one by retrieving it from the local database on click of back and next button. Initially when i am pressing next button its working well and displaying all the questions properly , it is working well too with simultaneously pressing of back button but When i press next next and then again back its displaying the question of next index instead of previous one.

```
    public void compareTableName()
    {

        Cursor c=db.getQuestionnum(username,surveyName,selectedQues,tablename);
        if(tablename.equals("email"))
        {
            selectedTableName=tablename;
            Log.e("table",selectedTableName);
            i_email=0;
            if(c.moveToPosition(i_email))
            {
                int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                Log.e("index",""+index);
                question_no= c.getInt(index);
                Log.e("question_no"," "+question_no);
                next_email++;
                back_email=-1;
                i_email++;
                //counter_email=1;

            }
            Bundle emailBundle=new Bundle();
            emailBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
            emailBundle.putString("username",username);
            emailBundle.putString("surveyname",surveyName);
            emailBundle.putString("quesname",selectedQues);
            EmailFragment emailFrag=new EmailFragment();//create the fragment instance for the top fragment
            emailFrag.setArguments(emailBundle);
            FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
            transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.MyFrameLayout,emailFrag, "email");
            transaction.commit();
        }
        if(tablename.equals("numerictext"))
        {
            selectedTableName=tablename;
            Log.e("table",selectedTableName);
            i_numeric=0;
            back_numeric=-1;
            //Cursor c=db.getQuestionnum(username,surveyName,selectedQues,tablename);
            if(c.moveToPosition(i_numeric))
            {
                int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                Log.e("index",""+index);
                question_no= c.getInt(index);
                Log.e("question_no"," "+question_no);
                next_numeric++;
                i_numeric++;
                //counter_numeric=1;

            }
            Bundle numericBundle=new Bundle();
            numericBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
            NumericFragment numericFrag=new NumericFragment();//create the fragment instance for the top fragment
            numericFrag.setArguments(numericBundle);
            FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
            transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.MyFrameLayout,numericFrag, "numeric");
            transaction.commit();
        }
        else if(tablename.equals("signature"))
        {
            selectedTableName=tablename;
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "inside else of onclick"+selectedTableName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("inside signature text","inside");
            i_signature=0;
            //Cursor c=db.getQuestionnum(username,surveyName,selectedQues,tablename);
            if(c.moveToPosition(i_signature))
            {
                int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                Log.e("index",""+index);
                question_no= c.getInt(index);
                Log.e("question_no"," "+question_no);
                next_signature++;
                i_signature++;
                //counter_sign=1;

            }

            Bundle signatureBundle=new Bundle();
            signatureBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
            //intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT",numericBundle);
            CaptureSignature signatureFrag=new CaptureSignature();
            signatureFrag.setArguments( signatureBundle);
            FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
            transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.MyFrameLayout,signatureFrag, "signature");
            //transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            transaction.commit();

        }
        else if(tablename.equals("information"))
        {
            selectedTableName=tablename;
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "inside else of onclick"+selectedTableName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("inside signature text","inside");
            i_information=0;
            //Cursor c=db.getQuestionnum(username,surveyName,selectedQues,tablename);
            if(c.moveToPosition(i_information))
            {
                int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                Log.e("index",""+index);
                question_no= c.getInt(index);
                Log.e("question_no"," "+question_no);
                next_info++;
                i_information++;
                //counter_info=1;

            }

            Bundle informationBundle=new Bundle();
            informationBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
            //intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT",numericBundle);
            InformationFragment informationFrag=new InformationFragment();
            informationFrag.setArguments(informationBundle);
            FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
            transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.MyFrameLayout,informationFrag, "information");
            //transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            transaction.commit();

        }

    }   


        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            if(v.getId()==R.id.next)
            {
                i++;
                nextButton++;
                backcounter--;
                Log.e("nextbutton",""+nextButton);
                Log.e("value of i",""+i);
                Toast.makeText(this,tablename+i,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                cursor=db.getAllRecordsTable(username, surveyName, selectedQues);

                counter_info=0;
                counter_numeric=0;
                counter_sign=0;
                counter_email=0;
                if(cursor.moveToPosition(i))
            {
                tablename=cursor.getString(0);
                Log.e("inside click",tablename);
                //Toast.makeText(this,tablename,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            Cursor c=db.getQuestionnum(username,surveyName,selectedQues,tablename); 
            if(tablename.equals("numerictext"))
                {

                    selectedTableName=tablename;
                    tableLastClicked=selectedTableName;
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "inside else of onclick"+selectedTableName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("inside numerci text","inside");
                    Log.e("value","before"+i_numeric);
                    counter_info=1;
                    //next_numeric=0;
                    //next_numeric++;
                    //if(backcounter!=1)
                    //{
                        if(i_numeric==-1)
                        i_numeric=0;

                        if(tableBackClicked.equals("numerictext"))
                        {
                                i_numeric++;
                                tableBackClicked="";
                        }

                    /*else
                        i_numeric++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i_numeric=next_numeric;
                    }
                    //counter=0;

                    /*if(counter_numeric!=1)
                    {
                        if(i_numeric>=1)
                        {
                            i_numeric++;
                        }
                    }
                    if(counter_numeric==1)
                    {
                        i_numeric++;
                        counter_numeric=0;
                    }*/

                    if(c.moveToPosition(i_numeric))
                    {
                        //if(i_numeric==0)
                        i_numeric++;
                        int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                        Log.e("index",""+index);
                        question_no= c.getInt(index);
                        Log.e("question_no"," "+question_no);
                        Toast.makeText(this,"question no is"+question_no,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                    }
                    Log.e("value numeric","after"+i_numeric);

                    Bundle numericBundle=new Bundle();
                    numericBundle.putString("username",username);
                    numericBundle.putString("surveyname",surveyName);
                    numericBundle.putString("quesname",selectedQues);
                    numericBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
                    //intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT",numericBundle);
                    NumericFragment numericFrag=new NumericFragment();
                    numericFrag.setArguments( numericBundle);
                    FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
                    transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.MyFrameLayout,numericFrag, "numeric");
                    //transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    transaction.commit();
               }
                else if(tablename.equals("signature"))
                {
                    selectedTableName=tablename;
                    tableLastClicked=selectedTableName;
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "last clicked"+selectedTableName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("inside signature text","inside");
                    Log.e("value sign","before"+i_signature);
                    //back_signature=-1;
                    //if(backcounter!=1)
                    //{
                        if(i_signature==-1)
                            i_signature=0;

                        if(tableBackClicked.equals("signature"))
                        {
                            i_signature++;
                            tableBackClicked="";
                        }
                        /*else
                            next_signature++;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        i_signature=next_signature;
                    }
                    //counter=0;
                    /*if(counter_sign!=1)
                    {
                        if(i_signature>=1)
                        {
                            i_signature++;
                        }
                    }
                    if(counter_sign==1)
                    {
                        i_signature++;
                        counter_sign=0;
                    }*/
                    Log.e("value sign","before"+i_signature);
                    //Cursor c=db.getQuestionnum(username,surveyName,selectedQues,tablename);
                    //counter_sign=1;
                    if(c.moveToPosition(i_signature))
                    {
                        //if(i_signature==0)
                            i_signature++;
                        int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                        Log.e("index",""+index);
                        question_no= c.getInt(index);
                        Log.e("question_no"," "+question_no);

                    }

                    Bundle signatureBundle=new Bundle();
                    signatureBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
                    signatureBundle.putString("username",username);
                    signatureBundle.putString("surveyname",surveyName);
                    signatureBundle.putString("quesname",selectedQues);
                    //intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT",numericBundle);
                    CaptureSignature signatureFrag=new CaptureSignature();
                    signatureFrag.setArguments( signatureBundle);
                    FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
                    transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.MyFrameLayout,signatureFrag, "signature");
                    //transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    transaction.commit();

        }
        else if(tablename.equals("information"))
        {
            selectedTableName=tablename;
            tableLastClicked=selectedTableName;
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " last click"+tableLastClicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("inside information text","inside");
            Log.e("i_information","before"+i_information);
            Log.e("value info","before"+i_information);
            //counter_info=1;
            //Log.e("backcounter",""+backcounter);
            //next_info++;
            //back_info=-1;
            //if(backcounter!=1)
            //{
                if(i_information==-1)
                    i_information=0;

                if(tableBackClicked.equals("information"))
                {
                    i_information++;
                    tableBackClicked="";
                }
                /*else
                    i_information++;
            }
            else
            {
                i_information=next_info;
            }



            /*if(counter_info!=1)
            {
                if(i_information>1)
                {
                    i_information++;
                }
            }
            if(counter_info==1)
            {
                i_information++;
                counter_info=0;
            }*/

            //db.open();
            //Cursor c=db.getQuestionnum(username,surveyName,selectedQues,tablename);
            if(c.moveToPosition(i_information))
            {
                int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                Log.e("index",""+index);
                question_no= c.getInt(index);
                Log.e("question_no"," "+question_no);
                //if(i_information==0)
                    i_information++;

            }
            Log.e("value info","after"+i_information);
            Bundle informationBundle=new Bundle();
            informationBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
            informationBundle.putString("username",username);
            informationBundle.putString("surveyname",surveyName);
            informationBundle.putString("quesname",selectedQues);
            InformationFragment informationFrag=new InformationFragment();
            informationFrag.setArguments(informationBundle);
            FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
            transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.MyFrameLayout,informationFrag, "information");
            //transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            transaction.commit();

        }
        else if(tablename.equals("email"))
        {
            selectedTableName=tablename;
            tableLastClicked=selectedTableName;
            Log.e("table",tableLastClicked);
            Log.e("value email","before"+i_email);
            /*if(backn==1)
            {
                i_email++;
            }*/
            //e=-1;
            /*back_email=-1;*/
            next_email=0;
            next_email++;
            //Log.e("e",""+e);
            //Log.e("counter inside email",""+counter);
            /*if(counter!=1)
            {
                Log.e("incounter","");*/
                if(i_email==-1)
                {
                    i_email=0;
                }

                if(tableBackClicked.equals("email"))
                {
                    i_email++;
                    tableBackClicked="";
                }


                /*else
                {
                    Log.e("else","");
                    i_email++;
                }
            }
            /*if(counter==1)
            {
                i_email=next_email1;
            }*/
            //Log.e("e1",""+e1);
            /*if(e1!=-1)
            {
                i_email++;
            }*/
            //counter=0;
            /*if(counter_email!=1)
            {
                if(i_email>1)
                {
                    i_email++;
                }
            }*/
            //counter_email=1;
            /*if(counter_email==1||i_email==2)
            {
                i_email++;
            }*/

            //db.open();
            //Cursor c=db.getQuestionnum(username,surveyName,selectedQues,tablename);

            if(c.moveToPosition(i_email))
            {
                //if(i_email==0)
                i_email++;
                Log.e("inside","email table");
                int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                Log.e("index",""+index);
                question_no= c.getInt(index);
                Log.e("question_no"," "+question_no);


            }
            Log.e("value email","after"+i_email);
            Bundle emailBundle=new Bundle();
            emailBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
            emailBundle.putString("username",username);
            emailBundle.putString("surveyname",surveyName);
            emailBundle.putString("quesname",selectedQues);
            EmailFragment emailFrag=new EmailFragment();//create the fragment instance for the top fragment
            emailFrag.setArguments(emailBundle);
            FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
            transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.MyFrameLayout,emailFrag, "email");
            transaction.commit();
        }
                c.close();
}

        else
        {
            i--;
            backcounter++;
            nextButton--;
            Log.e("backcounter",""+backcounter);

            Log.e("value of i",""+i);
            Toast.makeText(this,""+i,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            cursor=db.getAllRecordsTable(username, surveyName, selectedQues);
        if(cursor.moveToPosition(i))
        {
            tablename=cursor.getString(0);
            Log.e("inside click",tablename);
            Toast.makeText(this,tablename,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        Cursor c=db.getQuestionnum(username,surveyName,selectedQues,tablename); 
        Toast.makeText(this,"value of curosr"+c.getCount(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(tablename.equals("numerictext"))
            {

                selectedTableName=tablename;
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "inside else of onclick"+selectedTableName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("inside numerci text","inside");
                Toast.makeText(this,"inside numeric text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("value i","before"+i_numeric);
                //Log.e("back numeric",""+back_numeric);


                /*if(counter_numeric!=1)
                {
                    back_numeric++;
                }
                if(back_numeric==0)
                {
                    i_numeric=next_numeric;
                }
                else*/
                Log.e("table last clicked",tableLastClicked);
                if(tableLastClicked.equals("numerictext"))
                {
                    i_numeric=i_numeric-2;
                    tableLastClicked="";
                }
                else
                    i_numeric--;
                back_numeric=0;

                //next_numeric--;
                /*if(counter_numeric!=0)
                {
                    i_numeric--;
                }*/
                Log.e("value i","after"+i_numeric);
                if(c.moveToPosition(i_numeric))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"inside numeric text"+i_numeric,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                    Log.e("index",""+index);
                    question_no= c.getInt(index);
                    Log.e("question_no"," "+question_no);
                    //counter_numeric++;
                    //Log.e("count","before"+counter_numeric);
                }
                Bundle numericBundle=new Bundle();
                numericBundle.putString("username",username);
                numericBundle.putString("surveyname",surveyName);
                numericBundle.putString("quesname",selectedQues);
                numericBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
                //intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT",numericBundle);
                NumericFragment numericFrag=new NumericFragment();
                numericFrag.setArguments( numericBundle);
                FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
                transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.MyFrameLayout,numericFrag, "numeric");
                //transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                transaction.commit();
           }
            else if(tablename.equals("signature"))
            {
                selectedTableName=tablename;
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "inside else of onclick"+selectedTableName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("inside signature text","inside");

                Log.e("table last clicked",tableLastClicked);
                if(tableLastClicked.equals("signature"))
                {
                    i_signature=i_signature-2;
                    tableLastClicked="";
                }
                else
                    i_signature--;
                back_signature=0;

                //Cursor c=db.getQuestionnum(username,surveyName,selectedQues,tablename);
                Log.e("value i","before"+i_signature);
                /*if(counter_sign!=0)
                {
                    i_signature--;
                }*/
                /*if(counter_sign!=1)
                    back_signature++;
                if(back_signature==0)
                {
                    i_signature=next_signature;
                }
                else
                    i_signature--;

                next_sign=i_signature;*/
                Log.e("value i","after"+i_signature);
                if(c.moveToPosition(i_signature))
                {

                    Toast.makeText(this,"inside signature"+i_signature,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                    Log.e("index",""+index);
                    question_no= c.getInt(index);
                    Log.e("question_no"," "+question_no);
                    //counter_sign++;
                    Log.e("count","sign"+counter_sign);

                }

                Bundle signatureBundle=new Bundle();
                signatureBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
                signatureBundle.putString("username",username);
                signatureBundle.putString("surveyname",surveyName);
                signatureBundle.putString("quesname",selectedQues);
                //intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT",numericBundle);
                CaptureSignature signatureFrag=new CaptureSignature();
                signatureFrag.setArguments( signatureBundle);
                FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
                transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.MyFrameLayout,signatureFrag, "signature");
                //transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                transaction.commit();

    }
    else if(tablename.equals("information"))
    {
        selectedTableName=tablename;
        tableBackClicked=selectedTableName;
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "inside else of onclick"+selectedTableName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("inside info text","inside");
        Log.e("value i","before"+i_information);
        //if(counter_info!=0)
        Log.e("table last clicked",tableLastClicked);
        if(tableLastClicked.equals("information"))
        {
            i_information=i_information-2;
            tableLastClicked="";
        }
        else
            i_information--;
        back_info=0;


        //db.open();
        //Cursor c=db.getQuestionnum(username,surveyName,selectedQues,tablename);
        /*if(counter_info!=1)
        {
            back_info++;
        }
        if(back_info==0)
        {
            i_information=next_info;
        }
        else
            i_information--;
        next_info--;
        Log.e("next_info",""+next_info);*/

        Log.e("value i","after"+i_information);
        /*Log.e("valuebackinfo",""+back_info);

        next_information=i_information;*/

        if(c.moveToPosition(i_information))
        {

            Toast.makeText(this,"inside information"+i_information,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
            Log.e("index",""+index);
            question_no= c.getInt(index);
            Log.e("question_no"," "+question_no);

        }

        Bundle informationBundle=new Bundle();
        informationBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
        informationBundle.putString("username",username);
        informationBundle.putString("surveyname",surveyName);
        informationBundle.putString("quesname",selectedQues);
        //intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT",numericBundle);
        InformationFragment informationFrag=new InformationFragment();
        informationFrag.setArguments(informationBundle);
        FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
        transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.MyFrameLayout,informationFrag, "information");
        //transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        transaction.commit();

    }
    else if(tablename.equals("email"))
    {
        selectedTableName=tablename;
        tableBackClicked=selectedTableName;
        Log.e("table",selectedTableName);
        //db.open();
        //Cursor c=db.getQuestionnum(username,surveyName,selectedQues,tablename);
        Log.e("value of curosr",""+c.getCount());
        Log.e("value i","before"+i_email);
        //Log.e("e back",""+e);
        //e1=-1;
        //Log.e("e1",""+e);
        //e1++;
        //Log.e("e1",""+e);
        //backn=1;
        /*e++;
        if(e==0)
        {
            i_email--;
        }
        if(counter_email!=0)
            i_email--;*/
        Log.e("before",""+i_email);

        /*if(counter_email!=1)
        {
            back_email++;
        }
        if(back_email==0)
        {
            i_email=next_email;
        }
        else*/
        //back_email++;
        //Log.e("back_email",""+back_email);
        Log.e("table last clicked",tableLastClicked);
        if(tableLastClicked.equals("email"))
        {
            i_email=i_email-2;
            tableLastClicked="";
        }
        else
            i_email--;
        back_email=0;

        //Log.e("after",""+next_email);
        Log.e("value i","after"+i_email);
        if(c.moveToPosition(i_email))
        {
            Log.e("inside","email table");
            Toast.makeText(this,"inside email"+i_email,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
            Log.e("index",""+index);
            question_no= c.getInt(index);
            Log.e("question_no of email"," "+question_no);
            //counter_email++;
            //Log.e("counter","email"+counter_email);

        }
        Bundle emailBundle=new Bundle();
        emailBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
        emailBundle.putString("username",username);
        emailBundle.putString("surveyname",surveyName);
        emailBundle.putString("quesname",selectedQues);
        EmailFragment emailFrag=new EmailFragment();//create the fragment instance for the top fragment
        emailFrag.setArguments(emailBundle);
        FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
        transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.MyFrameLayout,emailFrag, "email");
        transaction.commit();
    }
    c.close();
 }

}
```

}

Comment: Lot of confusion with `next_email` , `back_email` , `i_email` and `counter_email`. Please post bit more code and logcat with printed all `Log.e` and why `back_email = -1`, is it make any sense?

Comment: @ManishDubey: ignore these as these are not being used and dsnt have any effect on my code. and m not getting any error so there is no use of log cat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution for my question.

```
public void getTableName()
    {
        cursor=db.getAllRecordsTable(username, surveyName, selectedQues);
        lastques=cursor.getCount();
        if(cursor.moveToPosition(i))
        {
            tablename=cursor.getString(0);
        }
        cursor.close();

    }
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public void compareTableName()
        {

            Cursor c=db.getQuestionnum(username,surveyName,selectedQues);
            j=0;
            if(tablename.equals("email"))
            {
                selectedTableName=tablename;
                if(c.moveToPosition(j))
                {
                    int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                    question_no= c.getInt(index);
                    db.insertQuestion(question_no);
                }
                Bundle emailBundle=new Bundle();
                emailBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
                emailBundle.putString("username",username);
                emailBundle.putString("surveyname",surveyName);
                emailBundle.putString("quesname",selectedQues);
                EmailFragment emailFrag=new EmailFragment();//create the fragment instance for the top fragment
                emailFrag.setArguments(emailBundle);
                FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
                transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.add(R.id.MyFrameLayout,emailFrag, "email");
                transaction.commit();
            }
            if(tablename.equals("numerictext"))
            {
                selectedTableName=tablename;
                if(c.moveToPosition(j))
                {
                    int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                    question_no= c.getInt(index);
                    db.insertQuestion(question_no);
                }
                Bundle numericBundle=new Bundle();
                numericBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
                numericBundle.putString("username",username);
                numericBundle.putString("surveyname",surveyName);
                numericBundle.putString("quesname",selectedQues);
                NumericFragment numericFrag=new NumericFragment();//create the fragment instance for the top fragment
                numericFrag.setArguments(numericBundle);
                FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
                transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.add(R.id.MyFrameLayout,numericFrag, "numeric");
                transaction.commit();
            }
            else if(tablename.equals("signature"))
            {
                selectedTableName=tablename;
                if(c.moveToPosition(j))
                {
                    int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                    question_no= c.getInt(index);
                    db.insertQuestion(question_no);
                }

                Bundle signatureBundle=new Bundle();
                signatureBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
                signatureBundle.putString("username",username);
                signatureBundle.putString("surveyname",surveyName);
                signatureBundle.putString("quesname",selectedQues);
                CaptureSignature signatureFrag=new CaptureSignature();
                signatureFrag.setArguments( signatureBundle);
                FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
                transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.add(R.id.MyFrameLayout,signatureFrag, "signature");
                //transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                transaction.commit();

            }
            else if(tablename.equals("information"))
            {
                selectedTableName=tablename;
                if(c.moveToPosition(j))
                {
                    int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                    question_no= c.getInt(index);
                    db.insertQuestion(question_no);
                }

                Bundle informationBundle=new Bundle();
                informationBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
                informationBundle.putString("username",username);
                informationBundle.putString("surveyname",surveyName);
                informationBundle.putString("quesname",selectedQues);
                InformationFragment informationFrag=new InformationFragment();
                informationFrag.setArguments(informationBundle);
                FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
                transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.add(R.id.MyFrameLayout,informationFrag, "information");
                transaction.commit();

            }
            else if(tablename.equals("signleselect"))
            {
                selectedTableName=tablename;
                if(c.moveToPosition(j))
                {
                    int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                    question_no= c.getInt(index);
                    db.insertQuestion(question_no);
                }

                Bundle signleSelectBundle=new Bundle();
                signleSelectBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
                signleSelectBundle.putString("username",username);
                signleSelectBundle.putString("surveyname",surveyName);
                signleSelectBundle.putString("quesname",selectedQues);
                Single_Select singleSelectFrag=new Single_Select();
                singleSelectFrag.setArguments(signleSelectBundle);
                FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
                transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.add(R.id.MyFrameLayout, singleSelectFrag, "singleselect");
                transaction.commit();

            }
            c.close();

        }   
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {

                if(v.getId()==R.id.next)
                {
                    i++;
                    Toast.makeText(this,tablename+i,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    cursor=db.getAllRecordsTable(username, surveyName, selectedQues);
                    if(cursor.moveToPosition(i))
                    {
                        tablename=cursor.getString(0);
                        Log.e("inside click",tablename);
                    }


                Cursor c=db.getQuestionnum(username,surveyName,selectedQues);   
                if(valueQues!=0)
                {
                    db.insertQuestion(valueQues);
                    Log.e("lastquestion_no"," "+question_no);
                }
                valueQues=0;
                j++;
                if(tablename.equals("numerictext"))
                    {

                        selectedTableName=tablename;
                        if(c.moveToPosition(j))
                        {
                            int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                            Log.e("index",""+index);
                            question_no= c.getInt(index);
                            db.insertQuestion(question_no);
                        }

                        Bundle numericBundle=new Bundle();
                        numericBundle.putString("username",username);
                        numericBundle.putString("surveyname",surveyName);
                        numericBundle.putString("quesname",selectedQues);
                        numericBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
                        NumericFragment numericFrag=new NumericFragment();
                        numericFrag.setArguments( numericBundle);
                        FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
                        transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.MyFrameLayout,numericFrag, "numeric");
                        transaction.commit();
                   }
                    else if(tablename.equals("signature"))
                    {
                        selectedTableName=tablename;
                        if(c.moveToPosition(j))
                        {
                            int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                            question_no= c.getInt(index);
                            db.insertQuestion(question_no);
                        }

                        Bundle signatureBundle=new Bundle();
                        signatureBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
                        signatureBundle.putString("username",username);
                        signatureBundle.putString("surveyname",surveyName);
                        signatureBundle.putString("quesname",selectedQues);
                        CaptureSignature signatureFrag=new CaptureSignature();
                        signatureFrag.setArguments( signatureBundle);
                        FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
                        transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.MyFrameLayout,signatureFrag, "signature");
                        transaction.commit();

            }
            else if(tablename.equals("information"))
            {
                selectedTableName=tablename;
                if(c.moveToPosition(j))
                {
                    int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                    Log.e("index",""+index);
                    question_no= c.getInt(index);
                    db.insertQuestion(question_no);

                }
                Log.e("value info","after"+i_information);
                Bundle informationBundle=new Bundle();
                informationBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
                informationBundle.putString("username",username);
                informationBundle.putString("surveyname",surveyName);
                informationBundle.putString("quesname",selectedQues);
                //intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT",numericBundle);
                InformationFragment informationFrag=new InformationFragment();
                informationFrag.setArguments(informationBundle);
                FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
                transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.MyFrameLayout,informationFrag, "information");
                transaction.commit();
              }
            else if(tablename.equals("email"))
            {
                selectedTableName=tablename;
                if(c.moveToPosition(j))
                {
                    int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                    question_no= c.getInt(index);
                    db.insertQuestion(question_no);
                }
                Log.e("value email","after"+i_email);
                Bundle emailBundle=new Bundle();
                emailBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
                emailBundle.putString("username",username);
                emailBundle.putString("surveyname",surveyName);
                emailBundle.putString("quesname",selectedQues);
                EmailFragment emailFrag=new EmailFragment();//create the fragment instance for the top fragment
                emailFrag.setArguments(emailBundle);
                FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
                transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.MyFrameLayout,emailFrag, "email");
                transaction.commit();
            }
            else if(tablename.equals("signleselect"))
            {
                selectedTableName=tablename;
                if(c.moveToPosition(j))
                {
                    int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                    question_no= c.getInt(index);
                    db.insertQuestion(question_no);
                }

                Bundle signleSelectBundle=new Bundle();
                signleSelectBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
                signleSelectBundle.putString("username",username);
                signleSelectBundle.putString("surveyname",surveyName);
                signleSelectBundle.putString("quesname",selectedQues);
                Single_Select singleSelectFrag=new Single_Select();
                singleSelectFrag.setArguments(signleSelectBundle);
                FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
                transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.MyFrameLayout, singleSelectFrag, "singleselect");
                transaction.commit();

            }


            c.close();
            cursor.close();
    }

            else
            {
                i--;
                cursor=db.getAllRecordsTable(username, surveyName, selectedQues);
            if(cursor.moveToPosition(i))
            {
                tablename=cursor.getString(0);
            }
            db.deletequestion(question_no);
            Cursor c=db.getQuestion();
            int pos=c.getCount();
            pos--;
            j--;
            if(tablename.equals("numerictext"))
            {
                selectedTableName=tablename;
                if(c.moveToPosition(pos))
                {
                    int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                    question_no= c.getInt(index);
                    db.deletequestion(question_no);
                }
                Bundle numericBundle=new Bundle();
                numericBundle.putString("username",username);
                numericBundle.putString("surveyname",surveyName);
                numericBundle.putString("quesname",selectedQues);
                numericBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
                NumericFragment numericFrag=new NumericFragment();
                numericFrag.setArguments( numericBundle);
                FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
                transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.MyFrameLayout,numericFrag, "numeric");
                transaction.commit();
               }
                else if(tablename.equals("signature"))
                {
                    selectedTableName=tablename;
                    if(c.moveToPosition(pos))
                    {
                        int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                        question_no= c.getInt(index);
                        db.deletequestion(question_no);

                    }

                    Bundle signatureBundle=new Bundle();
                    signatureBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
                    signatureBundle.putString("username",username);
                    signatureBundle.putString("surveyname",surveyName);
                    signatureBundle.putString("quesname",selectedQues);
                    CaptureSignature signatureFrag=new CaptureSignature();
                    signatureFrag.setArguments( signatureBundle);
                    FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
                    transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.MyFrameLayout,signatureFrag, "signature");
                    transaction.commit();

        }
        else if(tablename.equals("information"))
        {
            selectedTableName=tablename;
            if(c.moveToPosition(pos))
            {
                int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                question_no= c.getInt(index);
                db.deletequestion(question_no);

            }

            Bundle informationBundle=new Bundle();
            informationBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
            informationBundle.putString("username",username);
            informationBundle.putString("surveyname",surveyName);
            informationBundle.putString("quesname",selectedQues);
            InformationFragment informationFrag=new InformationFragment();
            informationFrag.setArguments(informationBundle);
            FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
            transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.MyFrameLayout,informationFrag, "information");
            //transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            transaction.commit();

        }
        else if(tablename.equals("email"))
        {
            selectedTableName=tablename;
            if(c.moveToPosition(pos))
            {
                int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                question_no= c.getInt(index);
                db.deletequestion(question_no);
            }
            Bundle emailBundle=new Bundle();
            emailBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
            emailBundle.putString("username",username);
            emailBundle.putString("surveyname",surveyName);
            emailBundle.putString("quesname",selectedQues);
            EmailFragment emailFrag=new EmailFragment();//create the fragment instance for the top fragment
            emailFrag.setArguments(emailBundle);
            FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
            transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.MyFrameLayout,emailFrag, "email");
            transaction.commit();
        }
        else if(tablename.equals("signleselect"))
        {
            selectedTableName=tablename;
            if(c.moveToPosition(pos))
            {
                int index=c.getColumnIndex("question_no");
                question_no= c.getInt(index);
                db.insertQuestion(question_no);
            }

            Bundle signleSelectBundle=new Bundle();
            signleSelectBundle.putInt("questionnum",question_no);
            signleSelectBundle.putString("username",username);
            signleSelectBundle.putString("surveyname",surveyName);
            signleSelectBundle.putString("quesname",selectedQues);
            Single_Select singleSelectFrag=new Single_Select();
            singleSelectFrag.setArguments(signleSelectBundle);
            FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
            transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.MyFrameLayout, singleSelectFrag, "singleselect");
            transaction.commit();

        }
        c.close();
        valueQues=question_no;
     }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement this one

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (currentFragment instanceof IBackListener) {
            if (((IBackListener) currentFragment).onBackPressed())
                return;
        }

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
            resetActionBar();
            manager.popBackStack();
            return;
        }

        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra(SHOW_TOAST_ON_BACK, true)) {
            if (lastBackPressed + 3000 > System.currentTimeMillis())
                finish();
            else {
                if (!mNavLayout.isOpen() && slidingPaneEnabled)
                    mNavLayout.openPane();
                lastBackPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            if (!mNavLayout.isOpen() && slidingPaneEnabled)
                mNavLayout.openPane();
            else
                finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: it help you to check whether ur in the base activity,if so returns out calling press once again  or  first fragment or if you are in some other activity ,it clears all backstack entries  or  if you are standing on one of the main activity,it ask you press once again to go back and if u press again it go back by clearing all.

Comment: but it will not solve my problem...my problem is that for example i n on email fragment n it is displaying question first question from database that is curosr value 0 hence making value of i_email 1 ven i again press next and next question is of information fragment it displays the first question of cursor zero n increments i_information to 1 n ven i press back i_email is decremented and the previous question is displayed but ven i press next again that is the information fragment the value of i_information is still 1 but i need value at cursor 0.

Comment: then its a bug..its not a problem of back press . You have to close the db everytime, after completeing the task.

Comment: in case you need to show some value from Db.you need to write two queries.One get all from the db and another is your solution on back press it must give you one record from top of the db.

Comment: @ragiM.tech.: its not a bug but yes your second answers has given me a hint..now i think i can solve my problem. thanks a ton will post if evrything goes fine...

Comment: i have posted the solution see if u were suggesting the same or sumthing else... nyways my purpose has been solved.. thank u